# How to get location and file name of OCX in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, ocx

I can load up the control fine (pseudo code):

```
Set o = CreateObject("DevsoftCustom.CommControl")
```

Now, I need to find the file and directory for that ocx (so I can read the version stamp on the ocx, and read from a config file in that directory).

How is this done in C# and vb.net?  (This project is in vb.net)

Comment: Yes you can - you just need to read several registry keys - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265/COM-IDs-Registry-keys-in-a-nutshell

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Isn't there a more direct way to ask the OS based on the object/control name?

Comment: "Isn't there a more direct way to ask the OS" - why would you expect that? Most users of COM/OCX components want to just give the OS a simple name and get the object in return. They don't want to go poking around on the file system or think about activation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever COM has a lot of plumbing, so I thought it should have plumbing to answer this question. Mucking about in the registry is always possible, but I strongly prefer to let the COM subsystem "do the math"

Comment: And it does. And it doesn't then stick that plumbing in your face. It, of course, has to answer the question "where do I find this code", of course it does. But it doesn't expect the *consumers* to care about how it did its job.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know, I get it. Just hoped for a more direct path. The registry route is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, I need to find the file and directory for that ocx

Assuming you are not using private COM registration, such information is in the registry.

```
HKCR\CLSID\<SOME-GUID>\LocalServer="<path>"
```

...or:

```
HKCR\<PROG-ID>\CLSID=<GUID>  // use this GUID in the example above
```

Or if you don't want to use the registry you can make use of the native function `CLSIDFromProgID()`. [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here's an easy representation of *Microsoft Outlook Date Control* in [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx).

> You can use the OLE/COM Object Viewer to view a control's interfaces.

[image]

So in your case, look up the class ID in the registry based on the prog ID *"DevsoftCustom.CommControl"*

i.e.

1. Under **HKCR**, look for the key **DevsoftCustom.CommControl**
2. There will be a child key called **CLSID**, take note of the default value
3. Open **HKCR\CLSID**\ < *your-key-from-step-2* >
4. The path will be in a subkey called **LocalServer32**

Using the Office example:

[image]

Once you know how COM works, its easy to implement the above in c#.

> Isn't there a more direct way to ask the OS based on the object/control name?

Not that I'm aware of and as Damien mentioned, the point of COM (including OCX) is that you don't care where something is, you just want an instance.

The closest parallel is having a .NET assembly in the GAC where you want to create an instance of an object but don't want to have to worry about deploying the same assembly over and over on the same computer.  Of course, the GAC serves far more purposes than that so that's where the comparison ends.